# Create an array with consecutive seconds - strptime - KeyError : 0

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I am trying to create an array that converts minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to seconds and adds them consecutively.

I have a df with a timestamp as follows:

```
        Time        Temp.
0   14:12:58:8230    135
1   14:12:59:0190    185
2   14:12:59:2150    138
```

I do the following to retrieve the data and access all the Timestamp column with `datetime.strptime` and make the array. But, when running it, I seem to have a `KeyError : 0`.

```
elapsed_x = []
tmp_1 = []

for i in range (0, len(df)): 
    tmp = datetime.strptime(df.Time[i], '%H:%M:%S:%f') 
    tmp_ms = tmp.microsecond
    tmp_s = tmp.second
    tmp_min  = tmp.minute
    tmp_1.append(tmp_min*60 + tmp_s + tmp_ms/1000000)

for i in range (0, len(df)):     
    elapsed_x.append(tmp_1[i]-tmp_1[0])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typically, using loops with dataframes is the wrong idea

Comment: What is `type(df['Time'].iloc[0])`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta it a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas can process Timestamp in a vectorized way:

```
tm = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')

df['elapsed'] = (tm - tm.iloc[0]) / np.timedelta64(1,'s')

print(df['elapsed'])
```

gives:

```
0    0.000
1    0.196
2    0.392
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

First create datetime column, then calculate seconds and elapsed time.

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
df['seconds'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['datetime'].hour*3600 + x['datetime'].minute*60 + x['datetime'].second + x['datetime'].microsecond/10**6, axis=1)
df['elapsed'] = df['seconds'] - df['seconds'].iloc[0]
```

**Output:**

```
            Time  Temp                datetime    seconds  elapsed
0  14:12:58:8230   135 1900-01-01 14:12:58.823  51178.823    0.000
1  14:12:59:0190   185 1900-01-01 14:12:59.019  51179.019    0.196
2  14:12:59:2150   138 1900-01-01 14:12:59.215  51179.215    0.392
```